# how can I get value from json object in groovy

Tags: groovy, soapui

```
def RawRecordsDateRangeResponse = context.expand('${getRawRecordsForDateRange#Response}')   
    log.info RawRecordsDateRangeResponse
```

My response is:

```
{"2018-09-03":"https://dhap-dconnect-telemetry-data-dev2.s3.amazonaws.com/ULT/d83350d2-af56-11e8-b612-0242ac11001118/temperature/raw-2018-09-03.json"}
```

Here I want to get the value from the json response key as date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your response represents JSON document and it stores it in variable of type `String`. You can parse it using [**`groovy.json.JsonSlurper`**](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.12/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html) class. Consider following example:

```groovy
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def RawRecordsDateRangeResponse = context.expand('${getRawRecordsForDateRange#Response}')

def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(RawRecordsDateRangeResponse)

def url = json.'2018-09-03'

println url
```

Output:

```
https://dhap-dconnect-telemetry-data-dev2.s3.amazonaws.com/ULT/d83350d2-af56-11e8-b612-0242ac11001118/temperature/raw-2018-09-03.json
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's just the key of the JSON message you need rather than the value, you could use something like:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def rawRecordsDateRangeResponse = '''{"2018-09-03":"https://dhap-dconnect-telemetry-data-dev2.s3.amazonaws.com/ULT/d83350d2-af56-11e8-b612-0242ac11001118/temperature/raw-2018-09-03.json"}'''
def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(rawRecordsDateRangeResponse)

def date = json.collect({it.key})
print date
```

This produces `[2018-09-03]`.

Comment: def link = json.collect({it.value}) prints the json value similarly .